# Pass variable as path in loadtxt() in python

Tags: python, numpy

Can I pass variable as path or concat the variable; with the path name?

```
path="\page_1.txt"
input = np.loadtxt("folder".path, dtype='U', delimiter=',')
```

When I try to run this code, then I get following error.

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'path'

Comment: "folder" is a Python string, right?  Does a string have a '.path' method? No.  This is basic Python.  `path` is also a string.  Show us exactly the file name that you intend to use.  It isn't clear from your code.

Comment: I think what you want is to pass `os.path.join("folder", path)` as the first argument to `loadtxt`.  (Add the line `import os` to the beginning of your code.)

Comment: Of course "folder" is string, in python if there any thing write in double coat is known as string.Thank you for your valuable comment @hpaulj. Bye the way my problem solved now by blewittrb

Comment: In Python, the `.` syntax marks an attribute; while `+` is used to join strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, however you are approaching it incorrectly. Currently you are attempting to access a property of 'path' as though it is an object.

See below for correct approach:

```
path = "\page_1.txt"
input = np.loadtxt(path, dtype='U', delimiter=',')
```

Also, to address whether you can concat a variable (file name) with a path (folder that file is in), yes this is also possible.

```
path = "\where\i\keep\my\files"
file = "\page_1.txt"
input = np.loadtxt(path+file, dtype='U', delimiter=',')
```

Comment: I got problem again can you help me? from loadtxt() function [0 0 0 0 0] array is generate, As like as for multiple array generate from multiple page when I try to concad them, they turn in to 1d array. but I want "[[0 0 0 0 0 ][0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]" this format.how I do that.Thank you @blewittrb

Comment: Hi Toufik, can you comment the contents of the .txt file?

Comment: Yes I comment, but now it solved, thanks for asking :)